# What notable works are there that try to express the structures of linguistics by modelling them with Artificial Neural Networks (ANN)?

Tags: phonology, morphology, syntax-trees, feature-structures

I know of a few works in Phonology and 1 recent work in Semantics but I will not list these here since what I would really be looking for in an answer would be a survey paper or a comprehensive list.

And I know that connectivity is a no no, but if there is one thing I consider to be somewhat of a Tautology it is that whatever the language apparatus is exactly its function is most certainly carried out by a (non artificial) Neural Network.